# Is there a HTOP log

Tags: log-files

is there a log for HTOP - i think I accidentally killed something and things are going weird

Comment: Define "something", "things", and "weird".

Comment: well I need the log to find out what I killed

Comment: @P P - you should probably edit your question and describe what is happening (and what you expect to happen) so we can better help. Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 4):

[htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) does not keep logs.